# Setting value with mask based on other columns containing null values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to check certain columns (about 5 or 6) and if all are null, change another column called `has_nan` from `0` to `1`. I know how to filter/mask, but when using `loc` I get the dreaded `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

Here is a small example to illustrate, not exactly the same but it highlights the issue:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.randint(0,100,3), np.random.randint(0,100,3),
                 np.random.randint(0,100,3), np.random.randint(0,100,3)],
                 columns=['foo', 'bar', 'has_nan'])
for i in ['use_1', 'use_2']:
    df[i] = 2 * ['5'] + 2 * [np.nan]

df.loc[df.use_1.isna() & df.use_2.isna()]['has_nan'] = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `df.loc[df.use_1.isna() & df.use_2.isna(), 'has_nan'] = 'yes'` instead.

For more info I read https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

Answer (score 4):

[Avoid chained indexing.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) Here you can use a Boolean series:

```
df['has_nan'] = df[['use_1', 'use_2']].isnull().all(1)
```

Using a Boolean series, i.e. one containing `True` / `False` values only, is the *recommended* method.  If you insist on converting to `'yes'` / `'no'` strings, you may do so in a subsequent step via a dictionary mapping:

```
mapper = {1: 'yes', 0: 'no'}
df['has_nan'] = df['has_nan'].map(mapper)
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick. Would you consider jorijnsmit's answer to be chained indexing? It's extremely close to what I tried, yet doesn't raise this warning.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, jorijnsmit's answer is not chained indexing. Just inefficient as it doesn't rely on mapping Boolean series.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Just fyi I'm using your code in practice - decided to mark jorijnsmit as accepted as it's closer to what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

you mean this? :

```
df['has_nan'][df['column_name'].isna()] = 0
df['has_nan'][~df['column_name'].isna()] = 1
```

Comment: I get `SettingWithCopyWarning` when I do that

Comment: Well I get nothing as such. As long as you are sure this is what you want to do, I think you can ignore that.

Comment: OK thanks. I think I'll leave it open a little bit longer to see if anyone can expand on why this error happens, and best practices.

Comment: Absolutely. :)  Will follow this post too till then. :) however , when you use `.loc` you are slicing a part of the `df` and doing something with it, once sliced, if you reassign the `df` to the original one, your actual data is lost, I guess hence the warning

Comment: That's good to know. So your answer avoids that by not working with a slice?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

```
df['has_nan'][df.use_1.isna() & df.use_2.isna()] = 'yes'
```

When you do the following, it returns a copy (this is what the warning is intended for) and will not work:

```
df.loc[df.use_1.isna() & df.use_2.isna()]['has_nan'] = 'yes'
```

Both of these will give warning, you can silence it using:

```
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)
```

Read [Evaluation order matters](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters) for detailed explanation.